# Bootstrap modals - update the background shadow mask when updating the size / content of the modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal window that contains a form. In this modal is also a link that uses the `jQuery` function `.slideToggle()`. Pressing this link expands a div that is otherwise hidden. The size of the modal popover is therefore **dynamic**. When pressing this link I get the following effect:

[image]

The dark grey color is the default `Bootstrap` modal background shadow, the white box with some words is my modal popover, and the light grey background is my original background color.

So what I want to do is to update the size of my `Bootstrap` modal background shadow so it fills the whole view, also when the size of the modal changes.

Is there a simple way to do this?

I use `Rails` and my `HTML (HAML)` and `JS` is very simple in this case:

```
= link_to "#", "Click me to toggle",  id: "toggle"

# JS
$("#toggle").click ->
  $(".my-div").slideToggle()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following `Javascript (CoffeeScript)`:

```
$("#toggle").click ->
  $(".my-div").slideToggle(400, updateModalBackground)


updateModalBackground = ->
  modalHeightValue = $('.modal-body').height() + $('.modal-header').height() + $('.modal-footer').height() + 205

  windowHeight = $(window).height()

  if modalHeightValue < windowHeight
    modalHeightValue = windowHeight

  modalHeightString = modalHeightValue + 'px'
  $(".modal-backdrop").css('height': modalHeightString)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try `.handleUpdate()` on your modal dialog after content change
I've found this solution [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15483)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference